# $A$ is bounded if $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\|e^{ihA}-{\rm id}_\mathcal{H}\|=0$

Tags: adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

I am looking for the solution to the problem:

**Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Show that $A$ is bounded if and only if $$\lim_{h\to 0}\|e^{ihA}-{\rm id}_\mathcal{H}\|=0.$$ Here $h \in\mathbb R$ and $i^2=-1$.**

The if part is easy by Taylor expansion of $e^{ihA}$ and some estimation. But I do not know how to prove the only if part. I tried to prove the equivalent: **$A$ is unbounded then $$\lim_{h\to 0}\|e^{ihA}-{\rm id}_\mathcal{H}\|\ne 0.$$**

I stared with definition of unbounded operator $A$, i.e. there exists a sequence $x_n\in D(A)$ such that $$\dfrac{\|Ax_n\|}{\|x_n\|}\to \infty.$$ But how to derive from this that there exists a sequence $y_n\in D(A)$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|e^{ihA}y_n-y_n\|}{\|y_n\|}\to \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Spectral Theorem we can assume that $\mu$ is a measure on (some $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of ) $X$, $D\subset L^2(\mu)$, and $$A:D\to L^2(\mu)$$is given by $$Af(x)=m(x)f(x)$$for some measurable function $m:X\to\Bbb R$.

Now we have to show that $m\in L^\infty$ if and only if $$||e^{ihm}-1||_\infty\to0\quad(h\to0),$$which is not hard.

Comment: Could you please prove the if part in your argument?. It is hard for me.

Comment: Well, if $m(x)$ is "large" for a certain value of $x$ then there exists a "small" $h>0$ with $e^{ihm(x)}=-1$...

Comment: Can you tell more detail?

Comment: You  should do some of this  yourself.

Comment: I think if $m(x)$ large for a certain value of $x$, and $\|e^{ihm}-1\|_\infty \to 0$ as $h\to 0$ then $|e^{im(x)^{-1}m(x)}-1|\to 0$ as $m(x)\to \infty$. But $|e^{im(x)^{-1}m(x)}-1|=|e^i-1|\ne 0$, contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.